# Getting empty plots when using subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am having a problem using subplots in matplotlib. I am getting empty plots when using subplots. What is wrong with my implementation?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,20))
ax = 1
for column in passenger_train_df.columns.values.tolist():
    if column != 'Survived':
        fig.add_subplot(4, 3, ax)
        if column == 'Age':
            age_binned=pd.cut(passenger_train_df['Age'], 10)
            age_binned.sort_values(inplace=True)
            table= pd.crosstab(age_binned, passenger_train_df['Survived'])
        elif column == 'Fare':
            fare_binned=pd.cut(passenger_train_df['Fare'], 10)
            fare_binned.sort_values(inplace=True)
            table= pd.crosstab(fare_binned, passenger_train_df['Survived'])
        else:
            table= pd.crosstab(passenger_train_df[column], passenger_train_df['Survived'])
        table.div(table.sum(1).astype(float), axis=0).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
        ax+=1
```

Comment: HI @karim-afifi, and welcome to stack overflow. For this and future questions, consult [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help guide you when asking questions. One good tip in there is using minimal, complete, and verifiable examples. If you reduced your code to a few lines, it would improve the chances in receiving help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the axes that is created when you use `fig.add_subplot(4, 3, ax)`. You then need to pass this as an argument into the `plot` function:

So change `fig.add_subplot(4, 3, ax)` to

```
axes = fig.add_subplot(4, 3, ax)
```

And then when you plot, pass in `axes` as an argument using `ax=`:

```
table.div(table.sum(1).astype(float), axis=0).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=axes)
```